# How can I change the dependent variable to turn this nonlinear equation to the heat equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, change-of-variable

I have this equation $\frac{\partial V}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial x^2}+(\frac{\partial V}{\partial x})^2$ and i want to use the method of variable change to arrive to this equation $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}. $The initial conditions are $V=0,t=0,0<=x<=1 $ and the boundary conditions are $ \frac{\partial V}{\partial x}=1,x=0,t>0 $ and $V=0,x=1,t>0.$
How can i approach the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you put $u=e^V$, then
$$ u_t = e^V V_t $$
and
$$ u_{xx} = (V_x e^V)_x = (V_{xx}+V_x^2)e^{V}, $$
so
$$ V_t = V_{xx}+V_x^2  \implies u_t = u_{xx}. $$

Comment: Thank you so much! Will there be a change in the boundary and initial conditions?

Comment: If $V=0$, $u=1$. The derivative one's slightly more complicated, since it's about $V_x = u_x/u$, so you only have $u'(0,t)/u(0,t)=1$.